CK Editor 5 Custom Plugin and toolbar button
I want to create custom plugin in CK editor 5 to to add table template and add a button in toolbar in Html JavaScript.
I have to create custom plugin to add a custom html template directly in ck editor by adding a button in toolbar.
enter image description here
Html File
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/35.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="./custombutton.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <script>
        ClassicEditor.create(document.getElementById('editor'), {
            extraPlugins: [CustomButton],
        })
            .then((editor) => {
                console.log('Editor is ready');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>

// custombutton.js

class CustomButton extends CKEditorPlugin {
    // Declare plugin properties
    static get pluginName() {
      return 'CustomButton';
    }
  
    // Define the button configuration
    init() {
      const editor = this.editor;
  
      // Create a new button for the p tag
      const button = editor.ui.addButton('customButton', {
        label: 'Insert Paragraph',
        icon: 'fas fa-paragraph', // Assuming you're using Font Awesome icons
        command: 'insertParagraph', // Command name for button execution
      });
  
      // Register the command for the button
      editor.commands.add('insertParagraph', {
        // Function to execute when the button is clicked
        exec() {
          editor.model.change((writer) => {
            const paragraph = writer.createElement('p');
            writer.insertElement(paragraph);
          });
        },
      });
    }
  }
  
  // Register the plugin
  export default CustomButton;
  

